# how do i resolve promises

Tags: javascript, discord.js, commonjs

I read like through 10 pages on how to resolve promises but i still don't get it.
Info: I want to fetch a specific member of a discord server

Currently I have a async function with the promise inside that returns it but it gives me a message with "Invalid Body Form"

```js
async function mbr() {
     const mB = await client.guilds.cache.get("1037783624449282189").members.fetch(`${args[0]}`).then((m) => { return m; });
     return mB
}
let member = mbr()

if (member.roles.cache.has("1039983830389510305"))
```

Edit: It gives me this Error when i do a async Function inside a async function

```js
G:\Desktop\Minecraft Modding\Bedrock\_____\Server\legend\plugins\nodejs\discord-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:659
        throw new DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
              ^

DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
user_id[NUMBER_TYPE_COERCE]: Value "undefined" is not snowflake.
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (G:\Desktop\Minecraft Modding\Bedrock\_____\Server\legend\plugins\nodejs\discord-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:659:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (G:\Desktop\Minecraft Modding\Bedrock\_____\Server\legend\plugins\nodejs\discord-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:458:14)
    at async REST.request (G:\Desktop\Minecraft Modding\Bedrock\_____\Server\legend\plugins\nodejs\discord-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:902:22)
    at async GuildMemberManager._fetchSingle (G:\Desktop\Minecraft Modding\Bedrock\_____\Server\legend\plugins\nodejs\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberManager.js:489:18)
    at async mbr (G:\Desktop\Minecraft Modding\Bedrock\_____\Server\legend\plugins\nodejs\discord-bot\chatBridge\accountLink.js:8:32)
    at async G:\Desktop\Minecraft Modding\Bedrock\_____\Server\legend\plugins\nodejs\discord-bot\chatBridge\accountLink.js:11:30 {
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: undefined },
  rawError: {
    code: 50035,
    errors: {
      user_id: {
        _errors: [
          {
            code: 'NUMBER_TYPE_COERCE',
            message: 'Value "undefined" is not snowflake.'
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    message: 'Invalid Form Body'
  },
  code: 50035,
  status: 400,
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/1037783624449282189/members/undefined'
}
```

Comment: `let member = await mbr()` (inside top-level `await`)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl like this?

Comment: don't edit the original question.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl that gives me an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises need to be awaited, either by using `p.then(callback)`, or by using `await p`.

For example, this Promise:

```
const p = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve("Hello world!"), 100));
```

will resolve in 100 ms, and can be used either like this

```
p.then(message => console.log(message));
```

or like this

```
console.log(await p);
```

In short, your function:

```
async function mbr() {
     const mB = await client.guilds.cache.get("1037783624449282189").members.fetch(`${args[0]}`).then((m) => { return m; });
     return mB
}
```

can be resolved by either

```
mbr().then(member => {
   if (member.roles.cache.has("1039983830389510305")) { ... }
});
```

or

```
const member = await mbr();
if (member.roles.cache.has("1039983830389510305")) { ... }
```

Note that in order to use `await`, you must be in an async context! By default, Node.js's global scope is synchronous, so you need to wrap your code inside an anonymous async function, like so:

```
(async () => {

  const member = await mbr();
  if (member.roles.cache.has("1039983830389510305")) { ... }

})();  // <--  call immediately
```

Comment: it gives me this error message now (I Edited my post)

Comment: Unfortunately, the error has nothing to do with your original question. ... what is `args` anyway?

Comment: args is an string[] so an string array
// message is the message send by the player
const args = message.split(" ")

Answer (score 2):

You have three ways to accomplish this:

#### Top-level await

**Note:** If this is an option in your JavaScript runtime.

```js
let member = await mbr();
if (member.roles.cache.has("1039983830389510305")) {
  // ...
}
```

#### IIFE async

```js
(async () => {
  let member = await mbr();
  if (member.roles.cache.has("1039983830389510305")) {
    // ...
  }
})();
```

#### Promise resolution

```js
mbr()
  .then((member) => {
    if (member.roles.cache.has("1039983830389510305")) {
      // ...
    }
  });
```

Also, your `mbr` function can be simplified to:

```js
const mbr = async () =>
  client.guilds.cache
    .get("1037783624449282189").members
    .fetch(`${args[0]}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

`async`/`await` can be used to make the code for working with promises a lot more concise and readable.

**In case you don't know how promises work, here's a quick explanation:**

Promises are a way for developers to create asynchronous, non-blocking code that will run "at the same time" as the current code. All promises should eventually `resolve` or `reject`, which are callbacks that let developers run extra code after a promise is finished.

In Discord specifically, fetching members creates an api request, which could take any amount of time, so it returns a promise. In order to actually use the data from the promise, you have to retrieve the data after it's resolved, which can be easily accomplished with `async`/`await`.

```js
// since this function is async, it will ALWAYS return a promise
async function mbr() {
     // await can be used to pause code execution until the promise resolves
     // you don't need to use `.then()`, because await is already resolving your promise
     const mB = await client.guilds.cache.get("1037783624449282189").members.fetch(`${args[0]}`);
     // return the resolved value of the promise
     return mB
}

// you need to add await here, because mbr() now returns a promise itself
// make sure this code is placed in an async function or use top level awaits
let member = await mbr()

// you can now use the member object and the data it contains
if (member.roles.cache.has("1039983830389510305"))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```js
async function mbr() {
     const mB = await client.guilds.cache.get("1037783624449282189").members.fetch(`${args[0]}`).then((m) => { return m; });
     return mB
}
let member = await mbr()

if (member.roles.cache.has("1039983830389510305"))
```

Comment: True, but that `await` has to be inside another `async` function as well, so keep that in mind, or a "top level `await`" as Polywhirl says.

Comment: Why would anyone upvote this if it's not even an answer?!